# Pass Oracle Apex 5.0 IR Filter value to item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report that needs to pass values to items to my "Mass Edit" page.  The "Mass Edit" page will then allow the user to update multiple rows.  I am able to do this via tabular form, but I want to leverage Interactive Reports filter functionality.

I am trying to pass multiple filters from IR to multiple items.  I have a button 'Mass Edit' that redirects to my "Mass Edit" page that has item: "Item1".  When a user filters on the IR report for "DATE" and then presses the "Mass Edit" button the value from the filter is not being passed.

In the link builder for the Mass Edit Button > Set Items.  I have under Name: Item1 and Value: "#DATE#"  Do I have the wrong syntax?

Any insight is appreciated.

[image: IRFilter]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all kind of filters to an interactive report or even link to a saved report. It is pretty well [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldapp_rpt003.htm#HTMDB30108) in the section "Linking to interactive reports". Your interactive report needs a static id and then pretty much everything is possible.

Comment: I am not trying to pass a filter to another interactive report.  I am trying to pass a filter value from an IR to an item, not to another IR.  For example I have a date column, and I want to pass that filter value to a item that is on another page, not to another IR.

Comment: define the column as "link" and set the attributes in the link definition.

Comment: I was able to pass the date value with your suggestion, however  I need to be able to pass multiple filters from the IR and have created a button that links to another page but can't seem to pass "Date"  to my item, not sure if my syntax is wrong I have Item1 with Value #Date#.

Comment: what is the value that is passed ? You're being very cryptic about this. Create a test app that only does this to investigate the issue so you can share proper screenshots...